# remove asterisk from filename

Tags: rename

I have a bunch of filenames that look like this:

```
2501254200*.nc
```

I want to remove the asterisk. But when I use the following code:

```
mmv '***' '#1#2'
```

I get the error

```
2501254200*.nc -> : bad new name

Nothing done
```

How do I remove the * from the name?

Comment: Maybe try `'*\**'` as the pattern?

Comment: @muru that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use `mmv` much, but here it looks like you need the middle `*` to exactly match the `*` character in the filename. Since `*` is otherwise a pattern, try escaping the middle `*`:

```
mmv '*\**' '#1#2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `*` which you want to use literally. Try this:

```
for file in *\**; do  mv "$file" "${file/\*/}"; done
```

Or, if you have `perl-rename` (installed as `rename` on Debian and its derivatives like Ubuntu):

```
rename 's/\*//' *
```